# Model Instance Settings || Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I currently have an app that is meant to generate documents based on user-set settings. The settings are supposed to be read by the program based on the class's instance settings so that the program knows which setting it is generating documents for.

When creating the instance settings for the user to edit each model entry, the code works like this:

```
    setting = get_object_or_404(SettingsClass, pk=setting_pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SettingUpdateForm(instance=setting)
        return render(request, 'main/viewSettings.html', {'setting': setting, 'form':form})
    else:
        form =  SettingUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=setting)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('settingsHome')
```

So it uses the "get_object_or_404" function to return the instance that the user should be working in and tells the form to use that **instance** here :`form = SettingUpdateForm(instance=setting)`

However when I am trying to execute this while reading from the model , the same type of setup does not work. This is what I have set up in my views at the moment:

```
def printReports(request , reports_pk):
    pkForm = get_object_or_404(SettingsClass , pk=reports_pk)
    form= SettingsClass(instance=pkForm)

    complexName = form.Complex
```

I am basically trying to tell the program to work in a certain instance of the model and read items from there, like: `complexName = form.Complex`

If anyone has any solution or alternate way to setup something like this , please assist. I will add the my URLs, templates and views code below for better viewing

Views.py:

```
def reportsHome(request):
    model = SettingsClass.objects.all().order_by('Complex')

    content ={'model':model }
    return render(request, 'main/reportsHome.html' , content)

def printReports(request , reports_pk):
    pkForm = get_object_or_404(SettingsClass , pk=reports_pk)
    form= SettingsClass(instance=pkForm)

    complexName = form.Complex

    #CHECKING TRIAL BALANCE SETTINGS
    if form.Trial_balance_Year_to_date == True:
        printTrialBalanceYTD = True

        ### Printing Trial Balance PDF
        response = HttpResponse(content_type= 'application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition']= 'attachment; filename=TrialBalance' + \
            str(datetime.now()) + '.pdf'
        response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'

        #SQL STATEMENT
        baseSelect = 'SELECT '+ op5 + op4 + ' Debit , Credit FROM [?].[dbo].[PostGL] AS genLedger '
        xtrbYTD = baseSelect + trbYTD + op1 + op2 + op3 + op6

        cursor = cnxn.cursor();
        cursor.execute(baseTRBYear, [complexName], [complexName], [complexName], [one_yrs_ago]);
        xAll = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        xtrbYTD = []
        for row in xtrbYTD:
            rdict = {}
            rdict["Description"] = row[0]
            rdict["Account"] = row[1]
            rdict["Debit"] = row[2]
            rdict["Credit"] = row[3]
            arr_trbYTD.append(rdict)

        content =  {"arr_trbYTD":arr_trbYTD , 'xCreditTotal':xCreditTotal , 'xDebitTotal':xDebitTotal , 'complexName':complexName , 'openingBalances': openingBalances ,'printZero':printZero}
        html_string=render_to_string('main/pdf-trialbalance.html' , content)
        html=HTML(string=html_string)

        result=html.write_pdf()

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as output:
            output.write(result)
            output.flush()

            output.seek(0)
            response.write(output.read())

            return response

    else:
        printTrialBalanceYTD = False
```

urls.py:

```
#Reports
path('accConnect' , views.reportsHome, name='reportsHome'),
path('accConnect/printReports/<int:reports_pk>' , views.printReports , name='printReports')
```

TEMPLATES:

reportsHome.html:

```
{% block content%}
<h1 style=" text-align: center">Reports</h1>
<hr>
 <br>
 <div class="list-group">
     <a href="#" class='list-group-item active'>Print Single Complex's</a>
{% for x in model %}
    <a href="{% url 'printReports'  %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" >{{ x.Complex }} Reports</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

pdf-trialbalance.html:

```
{% block content%}
<h1 class = 'center'>Kyle Database Trial Balance</h1>
<br>

</div>
<br>
<br>

<div class="table-container">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <th >Account</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
    {% for arr_trbYTD in arr_trbYTD %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ arr_trbYTD.Description }}</td>
        <td>{{ arr_trbYTD.Account }}</td>
        <td>
        {%if arr_trbYTD.Debit > 0%}
            {{arr_trbYTD.Debit}}
        {%endif%}
        </td>
        <td>
        {%if arr_trbYTD.Credit > 0%}
          {{arr_trbYTD.Credit}}
        {%endif%}
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr >
    {% endfor %}
    <td> <b>Totals</b> </td>
    <td> </td>
    {% for xDebitTotal in xDebitTotal %}
    <td><b>R {{ xDebitTotal }}</b></td>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for xCreditTotal in xCreditTotal %}
    <td><b>R {{ xCreditTotal }}</b></td>
    {% endfor %}

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the error in the title, first you need to fix the usage of `url` in the template and pass the primary key of the `SettingsClass` instance with:

```
{% url 'printReports' x.pk %}
```

So:

```
{% for x in model %}
    <a href="{% url 'printReports' x.pk %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" >{{ x.Complex }} Reports</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And then in your view, you don't need to use a form to access the attributes from your `SettingsClass` instance, so you can just do something like:

```
def printReports(request , reports_pk):
    settings_instance = get_object_or_404(SettingsClass , pk=reports_pk)

    complexName = settings_instance.Complex

    #CHECKING TRIAL BALANCE SETTINGS
    if settings_instance.Trial_balance_Year_to_date == True:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the "reports" variable to context. that's why the PK value is empty. check the view that's rendering reportsHome.html and apply the necessary, variable to template eg:

```
def view_func(request)
......
return render(request, '<template_name>.html', {"report": report })
```